# How can I change the variable inside the if statement of switch statement in Golang?

Tags: go

I am a newbie in Golang and now I have a requirement to change a value inside the if statement.

Here is my dummy code.

```
package main
func main() {       
    a := "hi"
    pull_enable := true 
    switch a {
        case "hi":
        image_list := []float32{
            0,              
            2,
            }
        for image:=0; image<len(image_list); image++{
            if image == 0 {
                pull_enable = true 
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I define a variable **pull_enable** outside of switch statement, and I want to change this variable value in the if statement, but when I built it, it encountered an issue below.

```
# command-line-arguments
pull_enable declared but not used
```

I am wondering how I can fix this issue. Is there any idea?

Comment: You are never actually reading the value (or even changing its default value) so Go considers it superfluous. Once you start using the value, it will compile.

Comment: You fix the issue by actually using the `pull_enable` variable. E.g. add a `fmt.Println(pull_enable)` call to the end.

Comment: Changing the variable _would_ work, the problem is more fundamental: Your code is not a _valid Go program_. Valid Go programs must _use_ all its variables (and writing to but not reading a variable is not considered a use).

Comment: Thanks for you guys comment. I totally understood. Because I used Python a lot, it works in Python. However, when I learned to Golang, I do know how to write a proper way in Go. Is there any other way to achieve my goal such as using pointer?

Comment: I even if put the variable inside in the default of switch. `default: pullEnable = false` ideally, if the programme goes into the switch, it must use this variable. I do not understand why it is still not a valid go program.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := "hi"
    pullEnable := true
    switch a {
    case "hi":
        image_list := []float32{
            0,
            2,
        }
        for image := 0; image < len(image_list); image++ {
            if image == 0 {
                pullEnable = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(pullEnable)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But actually, I do not want to print the variable since my programme will be used in the CLI tool. So it has better not print unnecessary information.